# Java - Execute Commands to Update a Running form

Tags: java, forms, swing

I am new to java, I'm practing with netbeans ide right now. (Swing)

Basically, I am trying to make a basic color switching app (sounds silly but for practice purpose only) using 2 forms.

The first form will run first, the color changing form. And
The second form will run next, the form which will have a option what color you want to change the first form to.

I know how to do this but I have to run the first form first and do something like
color_switching_form form = new color_switching_form();
and do the commands like form.setColor(Color.BLUE)

but my question is, how to make this possible that you will run the Second Form(Color switching Form) first? And it will update its colors once I run the first form (Color Chooser) second? and choosing a color from there.

I tried to do this again
new color_switching_form(); 
and do the commands like form.setColor(Color.BLUE)
But this just makes another form. It will not update the current color switching form.

Comment: You'll want to do some research into the "model-view-controller" paradigm, which Swing is build on. The basic idea here is, you have a model, which is shared between the two windows. When the second window makes a change to the model, the model generates a "state has changed event" of some kind, which the first window will subscribe to. When triggered, the first window will determine which actions it needs to take in response to these event (ie, change color based on the current state of the model)

Comment: Now, I know someone will try and tell you to pass a reference of the first window to the second window. This is short sighted to say the least, as the second window has absolutley no reason for needing a reference to the first window, it allows it far to much access to information it doesn't need and could allow the second window to start doing things it should do (like adding/removing components or changing other state information). It would also tightly couple the two windows together, reducing the usability of the solution (so you can have multiple windows reacting to the changes)

Comment: By passing a reference of the first window to the second, you are coupling state - the second window MUST know how to apply the changes to the first. By relying on a model based solution, the second window doesn't care, it just needs to set the new color and all the other windows then decide how best to apply it - this is why, if some suggests doing so, you should ignore them